# Regex in Java - Match anything, except '*' character

Tags: java, regex

Okay, so I'm trying to create a regex, that will ensure these 2 things:

1. String contains two '*'
2. String ends with 3 digits

I've made something, which kind of works, but it does not ensure that there are only 2 *, since in these spaces between the *, it can happen that there is another *:

```
Pattern.compile(".*\\*.*\\*[0-9]{3}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

So, these .* can be **anything, any amount of characters, words and so on** except * because I need to ensure that there are only 2 '*'.

How could I do it?

Comment: `[^*]` matches anything but the `*` character.

Comment: Is mandatory to have something other than two * and last three numbers?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah, but it only works for characters? Let's say string is like abc*asd*123, it's not going to match

Comment: @JavaSamurai It's not, so it's like: anything*anything*3_digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^*]` matches anything but the `*` character so you could do

```
^(?:[^*]*\*){2}[^*]*\d{3}$
```

- `^` - start of line anchor
- `(?:`  - start of non-capturing group

  - `[^*]*` - match zero or more non `*` characters
  - `\*` - match on a `*`
- `)` - end of non-capturing group
- `{2}` - repeat this twice
- `[^*]*` - matching only on non `*` characters
- `\d{3}` - end with 3 digits
- `$` - end of line anchor

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WjXwOV/1)

---

In a comment you added the constraint that it should end with `*` followed by 3 digits. That could be done by removing `[^*]*` after `{2}`

```
^(?:[^*]*\*){2}\d{3}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2wJftC/1)

Comment: This seems to be working! Thank you. However, if I wanted to ensure that the string ends with * followed by 3 digits, how to do that in this case, keeping all other logic?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
^.*[\\*]{1}.*[\\*]{1}.*[0-9]{3}$
```

It ensure there are two * and end with 3 numbers

Comment: You'd get my vote if it worked but this matches strings with at least 2 `*` - not exactly 2 `*`.

Comment: Yes. I think I misunderstood the required part to have exactly 2 * I can change it to have ^* at all three places but it would be unnecessary clutter. Your solution is better.